# crash while updating the app from version (which doesn't have core data) to version (which has core data added newly)

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord, magicalrecord-2.2

I am using MagicalRecord for saving the Data into DB.And when i try to update the app to core data version .

I am getting exception on the first time i try to save some thing

```
[MagicalRecord saveWithBlockAndWait:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
            MenuModel *menuModel = [CDMenuModel insertInManagedObjectContext:localContext];
            menuModel.sectionTitle = tibbrLocalizedString(@"menu_view.menuItem_mainWall.menu", @"Main Wall");
            menuModel.indexPath = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
        }];
```

Please find the crash stack trace for your ref

And also let me know your finding based on the crash log below

```
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x38760627 objc_msgSend + 7
1   Foundation                      0x2e8e6029 -[NSError dealloc] + 57
2   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x38765b67 objc_object::sidetable_release(bool) + 171
3   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x387660cf (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 355
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2def74bd _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 13
5   Foundation                      0x2e8f08df -[NSAutoreleasePool drain] + 119
6   CoreData                        0x2dd37fbb -[NSManagedObjectContext save:] + 939
7   appname_test                            0x002f2f7b 0x8e000 + 2510715
8   CoreData                        0x2dd9b9cb developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 87
9   CoreData                        0x2dd9bb0f -[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:] + 111
10  appname_test                            0x002f2ecf 0x8e000 + 2510543
11  CoreData                        0x2dd9b9cb developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 87
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x38c3fd3d _dispatch_client_callout + 21
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x38c446bf _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 23
14  CoreData                        0x2dd9bb07 -[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:] + 103
15  appname_test                            0x001807e9 0x8e000 + 993257
16  appname_test                            0x002509d1 0x8e000 + 1845713
17  appname_test                            0x0026d497 0x8e000 + 1963159
18  appname_test                            0x00265be7 0x8e000 + 1932263
19  UIKit                           0x307f7a4f -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 515
20  UIKit                           0x307f780d -[UIViewController view] + 21
21  UIKit                           0x3086ec39 -[UIClientRotationContext initWithClient:toOrientation:duration:andWindow:] + 385
22  UIKit                           0x3086d59d -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:isRotating:] + 1197
23  UIKit                           0x3086d0e3 -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:] + 43
24  UIKit                           0x3086d06b -[UIWindow _setRotatableViewOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:] + 91
25  UIKit                           0x3086d003 -[UIWindow _setRotatableViewOrientation:duration:force:] + 39
26  UIKit                           0x3086567d __57-[UIWindow _updateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:force:]_block_invoke + 105
27  UIKit                           0x307f9695 -[UIWindow _updateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:force:] + 381
28  UIKit                           0x3086cd55 -[UIWindow setAutorotates:forceUpdateInterfaceOrientation:] + 693
29  UIKit                           0x3086c825 -[UIViewController _tryBecomeRootViewControllerInWindow:] + 157
30  UIKit                           0x307fe611 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 457
31  UIKit                           0x307fbdd5 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 301
32  UIKit                           0x30865a4d -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 57
33  appname_test                            0x0037ae55 0x8e000 + 3067477
34  UIKit                           0x30862cbd -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 273
35  UIKit                           0x3086260f -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1607
36  UIKit                           0x3085ccc5 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 717
37  UIKit                           0x307f8c93 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3547
38  UIKit                           0x307f7df5 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 69
39  UIKit                           0x3085c401 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 613
40  GraphicsServices                0x32e55b53 _PurpleEventCallback + 607
41  GraphicsServices                0x32e5573b PurpleEventCallback + 31
42  CoreFoundation                  0x2df8e845 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 33
43  CoreFoundation                  0x2df8e7df __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 343
44  CoreFoundation                  0x2df8cfab __CFRunLoopRun + 1403
45  CoreFoundation                  0x2def7765 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 521
46  CoreFoundation                  0x2def7547 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 103
47  UIKit                           0x3085b627 -[UIApplication _run] + 759
48  UIKit                           0x3085688d UIApplicationMain + 1133
49  appname_test                            0x0009b5cd 0x8e000 + 54733
50  libdyld.dylib                   0x38c54ab5 start + 1
```

Comment: Show the code you used to create the core data stack

Comment: Its all related to Magical Record Methods  And i just added this on applicationdidfinishlaunching                             [MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStack];

Comment: Its not crashing in simulator only on device and that too happening only enterprise builds..   I couldnot able to debug even where the exact issue lies

Comment: I am not very good at reading those logs but it looks like right after the save. A load of objects are released. If that's right then maybe some of them are not meant to be.

Comment: Its exactly crashing on this line of magicalRecord library                  [localContext MR_saveWithOptions:MRSaveParentContexts|MRSaveSynchronously completion:nil];
performBlockAndWait:saveBlock